# Bootstrap - Issue with Margins on Container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to set even left and right margins on a container using the Bootstrap spacing property **mx-#**, but this causes the container alignment to go crazy - see image attached. I want to apply margins to large, medium, and small breakpoints, but have the container stay centered. I've applied my own custom css of **max-width** to the container. Also, I already tried turning **box-sizing: border-box** on and off, but this didn't seem to help either. Any ideas how to fix this?[image]

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container bg-white text-dark px-4 my-lg-5 my-md-4 my-3 mx-3">
  <!--mx-lg-5 mx-md-3 mx-sm-0 // px-lg-4 px-md-3 px-sm-0 px-0-->
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-12'>
      <h3>About me</h3>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving these css properties as well, width:100%. also could you paste the code, it will be helpful to debug

Comment: Got it.. You can add mx-auto helper class. That will fix the issue.